# Pass object through Link in react router

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, react-router

Is it possible to pass an object via `Link` component in react-router?

Something like:
`<Link to='home' params={{myObj: obj}}> Click </Link>`

In the same way as I would pass `props` from the `Parent` to `Child` component.

If it's not possible what is the best way of achieving this:
I have a React + Flux app, and I render the table with some data. What I am trying to do is when I click on one of the rows it would take me to some *details* component for this row. The row has all of the data I need so I thought it would be great if I could just pass it through `Link`.

The other option would be to pass the `id` of the row in the url, read it in the *details* component and request the data from the store for by ID.

Not sure what is the best way of achieving the above...

Comment: Depending on how you fetch your data overall, I would say the latter option.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

So my final conclusion on this question is that I didn't think it through properly. It seemed natural just to pass my data through the `Link` so I can access them in my `Child` component. As [Colin Ramsay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125680/colin-ramsay) mentioned there is something called `state` in the `Link` but that's not the way to do it.
It would work fine when the data is passed through `Link` only if the user clicks on something and is taken to the `Child` component.

The problem comes when the user accesses the `url` which is used in `Link` then there is no way to get the data.

So the solution in my case was to pass the `ID` in `Link` params and then check if my `Store` has the data (user accesses it via `Link`) and then getting this data from the `Store`.

**Or** if the data is not in the `Store` call the `action` to fetch the data from the API.

Comment: In react-router 3.0.0 the Link component doesn't have the "params" attribute. How is it done for the current version ?

Comment: What is a proper use case for the "state" property in Link if it won't work when the URL is accessed directly?

Answer (score 15):

**It is possible to pass an object through a Link**. (it's not best practice, but it's possible)

Add your data within a query rather than params and stringify the object:

```js
<Link to={{ 
  pathname: `/blog/${post.id}`, 
  query: {
    title: post.title, 
    content: post.content,
    comments: JSON.stringify(post.comments)
  } 
}}>Read More...</Link>
```

Then in your child component parse the string back in to an object:

```
JSON.parse(this.props.comments)
```

Comment: but you need to refer to the react router official documentation to see how to pass object ot `to` prop on link , it is the same for `NavLink` no  difference here , yours are a little bit off of that but any way , upvoted... , but please update your answer for avoiding the future misguides ....

Comment: @a_m_dev thanks could expand on what you said? maybe posting your own answer based on what you saw on the docs would help future readers. looking at these docs https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink

Comment: @Pixelomo, How is the query object accessible in the component that the route renders?

Comment: @Ren see the end of my answer ```JSON.parse(this.props.comments)```

Comment: Try finding it under this.props.location.query.title . And you will be able to access the value.

Answer (score 12):

No, you can't pass an object in `params`, so I would agree with you that your best plan is to pass the id to a store, have the store emit a `CHANGE` event, and have components query the store for info.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible, you need to pass something that can be stored in the URL such as a string ID. You would then use that ID to perform a lookup of the object.

Comment: The only alternative would be to pass the object as JSON but either way you would still be storing it in a form that gets stored in the URL. There's also a state prop for Link that you could look at but it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could try JSON serializing it and then de-serializing it on the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

*Using react-roter-dom ver 5.1.2 and es6*

I solved the problem like this first I store it in the search part of Link to object meaning it is part of the url and supports a bookmark etc.

```
< Link to={{
          pathname: `${match.url}/${dogName}`,
          search: `choosenDog=${JSON.stringify({ ...dog })}` //dog is the object to pass along
        }
        } >
```

And then on the link we goto I get hold of it like this

```
const query = useQuery();
const dogString = query.get('choosenDog');
const dogObject  = JSON.parse(dogString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to pass object via `Link` component in react. All you have to do is to pass the object to state property of the component

```
<Link to='home' state={{myObj: obj}}> Click </Link>
```

Then after that you can access the object using useLocation() hook. Note that the object should be access in the path as defined in the `Link` to perperty

```
const {state} = useLocation();
console.log(state); // {myOgj: obj}
```