# how to pass props to Link(ed) to react-router components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Every React app  I've made (which is actually only one small one) uses the `actions up, data down` approach, where (as I understand it) components receive data from parent components by calling `this.props.somePropertyName`. I'm now trying out react-router [and none of the examples given](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples) seem to have child components receive data via `props` and, from what I can see, there's no easy to pass props to child components (other than the `<RouteHandler/>`. In the example below, I pass an endpoint to the HomePage component from the App. In the HomePage component, I get the data (a list of blog posts) and wish to pass individual post to the PostDetail component (as a prop) but I can't do it. I don't want to pass all the data using react-router "params" because whatever gets passed as in params ends up in the url.

Question: In the code below, how do I pass data to the linked to PostDetail components, so I can call things like `this.props.postBody` in the PostDetail component?

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
              <RouteHandler source="/my-api-data-source/"/>
            </div>
         )
    }
})

var routes = (
    <Route name="main path="/" handler={App}>
      <DefaultRoute name="homepage" handler={HomePage}>
      <Route name="post" path=":postId" hander={PostDetail}>
    </Route>

)

var HomeComponent = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function(){
        $.get(this.props.source, function (result){
            if(this.isMounted()){
                this.setState({
                    posts: result
                 })
             }
         }
    }
    render: function(){
        return (
           //code omitted --I loop through posts array to create a list of links to posts like this
            <ul>
                <li>Link to "post" params={postId: somePostId}>post.title</li>
                <li>Link to "post" params={postId: somePostId}>post.title</li>
                <li>Link to "post" params={postId: somePostId}>post.title</li>
            </ul>

         )
    }
})
```

Question: how do I pass data to the linked to PostDetail components, so I can call things like `this.props.postBody` in the PostDetail component? (Also, imagine that I had several different routes and wanted to pass different props to different routes)

```
var PostDetail = React.createClass({


    render: function(){
           return (
             <div>
                    <h2>want to call `this.props.title` here </h2>
                     want to call `this.props.postBody` here 
                     want to call `this.props.postComments` here etc
             </div>
           )
    }
)}
```

Note, my question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864720/react-router-pass-props-to-handler-component?rq=1) as the `props` in my question are coming from the HomePage route i.e. I can't wrap the PageDetail component with the HomePage component as a way to pass the props from HomePage to PageDetail (as is suggested by the SO answer I linked to)

Comment: You can't/shouldn't do it via `Link`. You could overstretch it and use [`Link`s `state`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#state) to do that. But I wouldn't recommend it. I asked the same question a while ago, please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168014/pass-object-through-link-in-react-router

Comment: ok thank you. What type of event handler are you using when `<Link>` is clicked. Is it on the component that renders the link or on the destination? Is there something special in the api or just jquery?

Comment: oh, sorry, stupid question. the params are accessible on the destination