# Uncaught Error: <Link>s rendered outside of a router context cannot navigate.(…) react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

this is my app.js

```
import Index from './index'
import WeatherEng from './weatherEng'
import WeatherAr from './weatherAr'

import {Router, hashHistory, Route} from 'react-router'
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Index}>
        <Route path="Arabic" component={WeatherAr}/>
        <Route path="english" component={WeatherEng}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>, document.queryString('.container')
)
```

and this index .js

```
import React  from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from "min-jquery";
import axios from "axios";
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import WeatherEng from './weatherEng'
import WeatherAr from './weatherAr'
import {Link} from 'react-router';


const urlP=`http://localhost:3000/blah`;

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={ 
      imagedayA:[],
      imagenightA:[]

      };
  }
   componentDidMount() {
     axios.get(urlP)
            .then(function (response) {
              console.log(response.data,"this is response")
              this.setState({
                imagedayA:response.data.today.iconday,
                imagenightA:response.data.today.iconnight,
              })  
          }.bind(this))
            .catch(function (response) {
              console.log(response);
          });
      }
  render(){
    return (
       <div>
            <button><Link to="WeaAr">another</Link></button>
            <button><Link to="WeaEng">English</Link></button>
            <div>{this.props.children}</div> 

        </div>

    );
  };
}


render(<App/>,document.querySelector('.container'));
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwcYH.jpg
I got new errors  Uncaught TypeError: document.queryString is not a function(…)
 Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route`.
acctually the main idea is i want when click on another button it give yo component and when click on english button it move me to english component

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Link` contains wrong `to` path, try this:

```
<button><Link to="Arabic">another</Link></button>
<button><Link to="english">English</Link></button>
```

And one more thing you are already `rendering` your `App component` through `React Router`, no need to `render` it again in `App` component by this:

`render(<App/>,document.querySelector('.container'));` 
 Remove this line.

Use this code:

```
import Index from './index'
import WeatherEng from './weatherEng'
import WeatherAr from './weatherAr'


ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Index}>
        <Route path="Arabic" component={WeatherAr}/>
        <Route path="english" component={WeatherEng}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>, document.getElementById('container')
)
```

Put this line in html file: `<div id='container'></div>`

Comment: did u imported `ReactDOM` in app.js file, because in ur code its not present ?? if not use these lines: `import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

Comment: ya i import it now its same thing

Comment: no its not working re open the link that i put it u ll see the errors

Comment: now this is app.js 
import Index from './index'
import WeatherEng from './weatherEng'
import WeatherAr from './weatherAr'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React  from 'react';

import {Router, hashHistory, Route} from 'react-router'
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Index}>
        <Route path="arabic" component={WeatherAr}/>
        <Route path="english" component={WeatherEng}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,document.querySelector('.container')


)

Comment: use this: `document.getElementById('container')` and put this line in html file: `<div id='container'></div>`

Comment: and this is index.js which main component
import React  from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from "min-jquery";
import axios from "axios";
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import WeatherEng from './weatherEng'
import WeatherAr from './weatherAr'
import {Link} from 'react-router';


const urlP=`http://localhost:3000/simplyamman/api/amman`;

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={ 
      imagedayA:[],
      imagenightA:[]
      };
  }

Comment: this complete for index.js
   componentDidMount() { axios.get(urlP)  .then(function (response) {
              this.setState({ imagedayA:response.data.today.iconday,
                imagenightA:response.data.today.iconnight })  }.bind(this))
            .catch(function (response) {         });
      } render(){
    return (
       <div> <div><button><Link to="arabic">Arabic</Link></button></div>
            <div><button><Link to="english">English</Link></button></div>
            <div>{this.props.children}</div></div>) }}render(<App/>,document.querySelector('.container'));

Comment: sorry my mistake, got confused with name index and app, try the updated code it will work :) delete the last two comments, got ur point :)

Comment: let me know if u need any help in this.

Comment: i try these             <button><Link to={"/Arabic"} >Arabic</Link></button>
            <button><Link to={"/english"} >English</Link></button>

and its give me components but data is empty how i can pass data that i put it in this.state

Comment: and this in componts how i try get data 
          <img className="today_imgAr" src={this.props.imagedayA}/>

          <p className="tempdayAar">{this.props.tempdayA}<span className="degree">&deg;</span></p>
by this.props

Comment: how i can pass the data

Comment: its not a good practice to pass the complete object data from link, u can pass some property name but dont pass the object data, use the concept of Store, redux of flux architecture, save your data their and fetch the data from store :)

Comment: check these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router   and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168014/pass-object-through-link-in-react-router, i think your original problem has been solved, plz mark the ans as correct :)